# mass changing wordpress permalinks

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

so I have this odd question that may not be possible to answer... Not really sure, but whatever; I'll ask it anyways... I have a permalink structure as follows:

```
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/gdp-lesson www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/gdp-test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/demand-lesson www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/demand-test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/supply-lesson www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/supply-test
```

And I have hundreds of pages at the end of the permalink like that. This is on a wordpress installation, so the page titles respectively are:

```
GDP - Lesson
GDP - Test

Demand - Lesson
Demand - Test

Supply - Lesson
Supply - Test
```

I'd like to see if it's possible to run some code or a script or something (idk) that will just modify the permalinks for each of these pages to make them look like:

```
www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/lesson www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/gdp/test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/lesson www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/demand/test

www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/lesson www.mydomain.com/courses/economics/supply/test
```

while keeping the page titles and everything else the same. I'm not sure if this is possible without screwing up a lot of stuff. If anyone could figure this out, I'd be forever grateful!

Comment: I'm sure there is a plugin for that; this might be helpful as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could export your database as a .sql file and open the .sql file in a text editor. From there, you can run a find and replace to change it to what you would like. Keep a back up of your database just incase you make a mistake.

Comment: swag this works... change the post_name to change a page's slug